# Converting a dynamic array into single object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic array which is like this.

```js
    var callData = [
        {
            "FIELD_1": "0763454333"
        },
        {
            "FIELD_2": "dgfdgfg"
        },
        {
            "FIELD_3": "fgfdgfdg"
        }
    ];
```

According to the user, these number of fields changes. If another user has more fields, there can be FIELD_4, FIELD_5 and so on. I fetch these data from db and put it into and array as above. Now I want to convert it a single object. I want it to look like this.

```js
    {
        "FIELD_1": "076355998", "FIELD_2": "933504395v", "FIELD_3": "123"
    }
```

Although I found converting solutions in stackoverflow, Those didn't solve my problem. How can I achieve this? Please guide.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Why has the result object different values?

Comment: Try to loop through object (for..in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `flatMap` function to return entries of each object and then use `Object.fromEntries` function to create an object from the entries

```js
var callData = [
  {"FIELD_1": "0763454333" },
  { "FIELD_2": "dgfdgfg" },
  { "FIELD_3": "fgfdgfdg" }
];

const res = Object.fromEntries(callData.flatMap(o => Object.entries(o)));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem.